# Can this series of integrals be simplified further?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I stumbled upon this series
$$\int_{a+n}^{b-n} f(x)\,dx \ + \int_{b+n}^{c-n} f(x)\,dx \ + \int_{c+n}^{d-n} f(x)\,dx \ $$
and I was wondering if this could be simplified further, hopefully to a single integral.

Comment: Unless $n\to 0$, I don't think there is much that you can do (in terms of getting a single integral).

Comment: Is $f$ periodic? do you have that information? maybe with that we can simplify a little more

Comment: The combination of integrals can be re-expressed as $$\int_{a+n}^{d-n} f(x)\,dx \ - \int_{b-n}^{b+n} f(x)\,dx \ - \int_{c-n}^{c+n} f(x)\,dx. $$  However, since nothing is known about the two rightmost integrals, with respect to the leftmost integral, I don't see how the two rightmost integrals can be eliminated.

Comment: @Zaragosa $f$ is not necessarily periodic. I was trying to simplify $$ \sum_{i=1}^{k-a}\int_{(a+n-1)+i}^{(a-n)+i}f(x)dx $$ for any function $f$, where $a,n$ and $k$ are constants. Can it be simplified further?

Comment: @RishitDutta I understand that $k-a\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 1}$, but what restriction does $n$ have? maybe $n<0$? I ask to play with the limits of integration.

Comment: @Zaragosa $n$ is not bounded, I was going to make it approach 0 in a subsequent step.

Comment: @Zaragosa I was going to solve this expression $$ \lim_{n \to 0}\frac{1}{n}[\int_{a}^{k}f(x)dx-\sum_{i=1}^{k-a}\int_{(a+n-1)+i}^{(a-n)+i}f(x)dx] $$

Comment: @RishitDutta It would be better if you modify your initial question, and show your intention to have a better context and be able to help you.